# Jersey with Java 5

Tags: java, jersey

What is the latest version of Jersey that will run with Java 5?  I found the [Jersey 1.3 documentation](http://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/jersey_1_3_is_released) saying that Java 6 is required but I'm having troubles finding previous versions of the docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are stuck with Java 5, your need to use [Jersey 1.2](http://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/jersey_1_2_is_released).

If the version is not mature enough for you, try [Spring 3](http://www.springsource.org/download) MVC for building REST webservices, works with Java 5:

- [Spring Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html)
- [Spring blog article](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/)
- [Build RESTful web services using Spring 3 (ibm)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/wa-spring3webserv/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

You sure? [Jersey 1.7 guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html) claims 1.5 works, with some additional jars.

Comment: Applications can compile but will not run with Jersey 1.7 attached.  It gives the dreaded "Bad version number in .class file" when I try to run it.  I don't think adding extra jars will help but I'll take a closer look at the documentation.

Comment: Indeed I could.  I was very surprised by the behavior.

Comment: Where does it claim that, I don't see anywhere in the docs a reference to 1.5. I did see this though:
""All Jersey components are built using Java SE 6 compiler. It means, you will also need at least Java SE 6 to be able to compile and run your application."

Comment: Yee - it's been many years, but I happened to notice your comment. It's clear on retrospect that 1.7 was transitioning to requiring Java 6. Yes there is the sentence you quote (and the reality), but there were scattered comments in the manual and in the original install instructions about using SE 5.