# Rest service with jdk5

Tags: java, rest, jersey, java-5

I am trying a JSON Rest service using jersey 1.18.
I am stuck up with jdk5. 
Could please help with the Jersey jar version compatible with jdk5. 
Or an example For rest service with jdk5?

Comment: Why are you stuck with a 14 years old JDK ?

Comment: @Berger not everyone has the luxury of *not* working on legacy stuff. You'd be surprised at the state of some systems I had to work on. 14 years is very little.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey with Java 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350008/jersey-with-java-5)